# iOS8,iOS9 [WKWebViewConfiguration setDataDetectorTypes: crach

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

When i use `wkwebview` on `iOS8`,`iOS9`，There was a crash

```
theConfiguration.dataDetectorTypes = WKDataDetectorTypeNone；
```

reason:

> -[WKWebViewConfiguration setDataDetectorTypes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x126e178d0 callStackSymbols:

so,how can i solve it????

Answer (score 0):

setDataDetectorTypes is available only from iOS 10. You have to add  `if #available(iOS 10.0, *) { ... }` into your code